# How to get the max value of 3 fields

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird-3.0

I have a table with integer fields like this:

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 6 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 5 | 7 | 1 |

1. First, I want to look for the max value in field3. It's 2.
2. Now, I want to look for the max value in field2, but only in records that have the max value from step 1. It's 6.
3. Now, I want to look for the max value in field1, but only in records that have the max value from step 2. It's 3

The result must be:

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 | 2 |

These numbers are just an example. They can be in range from 0 to max_int.

How to write an SQL query for Firebird 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by [user13964273](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13964273/user13964273) in the comments, you can use [`order by`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml.html#fblangref30-dml-select-orderby) and [`fetch`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-dml.html#fblangref30-dml-select-offsetfetch):

```sql
select field1, field2, field3 
from example3fields
order by field3 desc, field2 desc, field1 desc
fetch first 1 row only
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=fc6e6ae7f65dd6d51f8a7e1f23832f63)

You can also use the [window function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-windowfuncs.html) [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-windowfuncs-rankfuncs.html#fblangref30-windowfuncs-row-number) with the desired order for this:

```sql
select field1, field2, field3
from (
  select field1, field2, field3, 
    row_number() over(order by field3 desc, field2 desc, field1 desc) rownum
  from example3fields
)
where rownum = 1
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=e5fc80ecafb524efcefdbc548952f699)

The solution with `ORDER BY` is far simpler. Using a window function like [`DENSE_RANK`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref30/fblangref30-windowfuncs-rankfuncs.html#fblangref30-windowfuncs-dense-rank) could make sense if you want to find all matching rows (i.e. if there are multiple rows with the same maximum values).

Comment: May be simplier https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0&fiddle=fc6e6ae7f65dd6d51f8a7e1f23832f63

Comment: @user13964273 You're right, I'm not sure what I was thinking :)

Comment: Other columns are not a problem in simple cases but your solution is indeed more common.

Comment: @user13964273 I guess I initially wanted to use `DENSE_RANK` to return all matching rows (e.g. if there was more than one row with the same max values). Thanks for pointing out the simpler solution.